# Any way of returning 2 objects from a function without making a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a basic date converter and I need to update the the date every time the user enters an invalid date and is asked to input again. From this function below, I need both the object *day* and *year* returned.

```
def day_valid (month, dates, feb_day, month_days):

    day = int(dates[2:4])

    while month_days == 31 and day > 31:
        print ("Invalid day input.")
        print()
        dates = input_date()
        day = int(dates[2:4])

        if month_days == 31 and day < 32:
            break

    while month_days == 30 and day > 30:
        print ("Invalid day input.")
        print()
        dates = input_date()
        day = int(dates[2:4])

        if month_days == 30 and day < 31:
            break

    while month_days == feb_day and day > feb_day:
        print ("Invalid day input.")
        print()
        dates = input_date()
        day = int(dates[2:4])

        if month_days == feb_day and day <= feb_day:
            break


    return day
```

When a user types in 00102002 in MMDDYYYY format, there is no month. So the user is prompted to enter again, entering 01102005. The code still displays the date as 10 January *2002* and not *2005* .

If any one needs clarification on the code, please ask!

My main function:

```
def main():

    loop = "Y"

    print()
    print("Welcome to Date Converter!")
    print()

    while loop.upper () == "Y" :
        dates = input_date()

        year = int(dates[4:])

        month = month_valid(dates)
        feb_day = feb_days(year)

        month_days = month_Days(month, feb_day)

        day = day_valid(month, dates, feb_day, month_days)


        month_str = month_names(month)

        print()
        print("The date is " + str(day) + " " + month_str + " " + str(year))
        loop = str(input ("Do you want to re-run this program? Y/N: "))


main()
```

Comment: What's wrong with returning a tuple? Of course you can return a list or other iterable instead (and it'll even still be unpackable). Or you can create a class that hold the two values together. Or you can take a mutable parameter like a list and append values onto that instead of returning them. Or you can have a global registry of values with your own custom semantics on top of it. But none of those are better than  just doing the pythonic thing and returning a tuple.

Comment: Why don't you just return a `datetime` object?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds first of all like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/): someone wants to do X, and comes up with a solution requiring doing Y. They need help with Y, so request help to do Y. However, it turns out that Y is not an appropriate solution. By recognizing the XY Problem and asking how to do X instead, the person gets better help and more insight into X.

XY Problems also often look suspiciously like homework problems, since those are often of the form "write a program that does X, by doing Y".

It's OK to pose a question that you want to do X and tried to solve it using Y.

Anyway, that's why you're probably going to get low-effort answers. I'll make the effort :)

Anyway, going with the Y question :)

There is a readability practice that considers tuples harmful because you don't know what the purpose of the items in the tuple are. Consider instead creating an object that holds the things, each with its own attribute, and then return that.

Since you stated that you needed `day` and `year` returned:

```
class DayAndYear(object):
    def __init__(self, day, year):
        self.day = day
        self.year = year
```

And that's how you do it without making a tuple, and it increases the readability of your program, such as it is.

Now, going with the unstated X question:

- without knowing what `month_valid` does,
- assuming `feb_days` returns the number of days in February of the given year,
- assuming `month_Days` returns the number of days in the given month when it isn't February,

it seems that you want a function that will check if a string is a valid MMDDYYYY string.

```
def is_valid_date(s):
    """Checks if the given date is a valid MMDDYYYY string.

    Args:
        s (str): A date to check.
    Returns:
        bool: True if the date is valid, False otherwise.
    """
    if len(s) != 8:
        return False

    try:
        date = int(s[:2])
        month = int(s[2:4])
        year = int(s[4:])
    except ValueError:
        return False

    if month < 1 and month > 12:
        return False

    if month == 2:
        days_in_month = days_in_february(year)
    else:
        days_in_month = days_in_month(month)

    return date >= 1 and date <= days_in_month

def print_date(s):
    """Prints the given MMDDYYYY date, assuming it has already been checked for validity.

    Args:
        s (str): A date to print.
    """
    print("The date is {:d} {:s} {:d}.".format(
        int(s[2:4]), month_name(int(s[:2])), int(s[4:])))
```

I'd like to highlight a few general techniques to make your programs read better:

- We don't know X. A well-posed question is one with specifications for the input and output of the program.
- I've used verbose, readable function names.
- I've used function comments, complete with args, arg types, and return values so there's no guessing about what things do.
- I've chosen a split between checking validity and printing an already valid string. You can combine them. You can also return a string rather than print the date, and return instead the sentinel value None if the date was not valid.
- Don't compute any more than you have to. Note the early returns.
- No doubt there are library functions that will do this, but I've assumed you don't want to use any library functions.

The short key concepts:

- Readability: Programs should be almost as easy to read as prose in your native language.
- Readability: Function names should be descriptive.
- Readability: Comment your code.
- Readability: Choose a consistent format for functions and stick with it ("`month_Days`" vs "`feb_days`")
- Efficiency: Return early.
- Testability: Specify well what your program does in terms of inputs and outputs, give examples of good and bad inputs.
- Effectiveness: Use library functions.
- Stackoverflowness: Consider if your problem is an XY problem.